# Colocar uma barra no final da url (ou antes da interrogação)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Implementei este script, de troca de idiomas (ou troca de unidades, neste caso):

```js
   /*Aqui ele coleta a seleção*/
      $('#unidade').on('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('form_unidade').submit();
   });
```

```html
     <!-- Aqui se seleciona a unidade -->
          <form method='get' action='' id='form_unidade' >
      <select name='unidade' id="unidade" > 
       <option value='cidade-1' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['unidade']) && $_SESSION['unidade'] == 'cidade-1'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >São José do Rio Pardo</option>
       <option value='cidade-2' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['unidade']) && $_SESSION['unidade'] == 'cidade-2'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >Mococa</option>
      </select>
     </form>
          
          <!-- Ele aqui ele grava na sessão a unidade selecionada -->
          <?php

 if(isset($_GET['unidade']) && !empty($_GET['unidade'])){
  $_SESSION['unidade'] = $_GET['unidade'];

  if(isset($_SESSION['unidade']) && $_SESSION['unidade'] != $_GET['unidade']){
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'> location.reload(); </script>";
  }
 }


 if(isset($_SESSION['unidade'])){
  include "php/multi-unidades/unidade_".$_SESSION['unidade'].".php";
 }else{
  include "php/multi-unidades/cidade-1.php";
 }
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['unidade'])){
  $unidade = "sao-jose-do-rio-pardo";
 }else{
  $unidade = $_SESSION['unidade'];
 }          
          ?>
```

Funciona perfeitamente para a ocasião.
Se pudesse melhorar um detalhe, o link que ele gera fica assim:

http://localhost/site/contato?unidade=cidade-1

Há algumas páginas que isso causa problemas.

Nessa estrutura, seria possível que o link gerado tivesse uma barra antes da interrogação?

http://localhost/site/contato/?unidade=cidade-1

Answer (score -2):

Você tentou utilizar o window.location.href = "url_aqui", em vez de usar o location.reload?

Qual a finalidade disso que você está fazendo? A URL muda assim que você seleciona a unidade? Isso é salvo em banco de dados ou é um formulário de envio de e-mails?

Tem como fornecer mais informações a respeito caso o window.location.href não sirva?

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/264149)

Comment: Então responda à pergunta do rapaz por favor, ele tá precisando de ajuda. Se a minha ajuda não é o suficiente, então ajude ele, seria mais útil do que me repreender por tentar ajudar.

Comment: Jean, ninguém está de repreendendo, apenas você não entendeu o propósito do SOpt. Recomendo a leitura:  [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) , [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).

Comment: Tentei usar o window.location.href, mas ficou do mesmo jeito. Acho que o problema está na linha "document.getElementById('form_unidade').submit();". Uma opção que tinha tentado, sem sucesso e ajustar o .htaccess para colocar uma barra no final de todas as url.